# How would I write this query with DBIX::Class?

Tags: dbix-class

I've seen a few other questions on Stackoverflow that discuss sub-selects, but they usually relate to the use of multiple tables.  In most cases, a proper join could serve the same purpose.

However my query below refers to a single table.  How would I write this using DBIX::Class?

```
select  ID, username, email, role
from Employees
where (ID in 
    (select max(ID)
        from Employees
        where username = 'jsmith'
    ))
order by ID DESC
```

Thanks!

--
Edit 1: SQL code fix

Answer (score 1):

The [Cookbook](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aManual%3a%3aCookbook#Correlated-subqueries) has almost the exact same query as example.

Your SQL query doesn't make sense to me because the subquery returns a single id, so WHERE id = () would make more sense.
What are you trying to accomplish with it?

Comment: The ID returned would be the max(id) from the sub-select.  For example, if there are many records in the DB where username='jsmith', this query would give us the latest record.  Not exactly the best database structure, but it's what I have to work with.

I've found an appropriate solution however, it required a view to be created in the DB to do most of the grunt-work (only list the latest records via max ID for each user).